# Longest increasing subsequence when a number can be added to all numbers in a subarray

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, arrays, polynomial-time, longest-increasing-subsequence

A sequence $(a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n) $ and natural numbers $n$ and $k$ are given.

We want to calculate the longest (strictly) increasing subsequence of sequence $(b_1,b_2, \dots, b_n)$ for which there exist an interval of pointers $[l, r]$ and an integer $x$, $-k\le x\le k$, such that $b_i = a_i + x$ for $i \in [l, r]$, and $b_i = a_i$ for $i \notin [l, r]$.

Input: The natural numbers $n$, $k$ and the sequence $a$.

Output: The longest increasing subsequence that can be created through a sequence $b$.

I want to find a polynomial-time algorithm that solves this problem

I know how to find longest increasing subsequence in general.

I think we'll have to use Dynamic Programming.

Comment: Is x constant for all b_i? Is the array of b given, or is that what we're trying to find? This question needs to be clarified a lot. What exactly is it that we're looking to solve?

Comment: x is constant for all $b_i $ with $i \in [l, r]$. We want to find the longest increasing subsequence that can be created from the sequences b

Comment: What are the constraints for n and k? Are you looking for an answer that runs in a certain time complexity, or is a brute force solution ok?

Comment: @LogicalX they are natural numbers. And I would like an algorithm that runs in polynomial time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that runs in `O(n)` time. To explain the solution, we must make a few observations.

First, note that having a negative value of `x` has the same effect as a positive value (ex. having `x = -3` will produce a sequence `b` with the same longest increasing subsequence as `x = 3`) so we should only test positive values of `x`.

Given this, also note that it will never be sub-optimal to have the interval `[l, r]` be at the end of an increasing subsequence, as any optimal solution without `[l, r]` at the end can be turned into another optimal solution by simply extending `[l, r]` to go all the way to the end of the subsequence. It can be proved that extending `[l, r]` to the right will never make an increasing subsequence worse.

Thus, a naive solution would be to simply go through all possible optimal values of `l` for each possible value of `x`. This would give us an `O(nk)` algorithm. However, we can realize that all optimal solutions with `[l, r]` starting at a fixed `l`, another optimal solution can be made by simply increasing the value of x; the only purpose of the interval `[l, r]` is to 'fix' the step between `a[l-1]` and `a[l]` in order to maintain an increasing subsequence. Therefore, it is always optimal to set `x` to the highest value possible -- in this case, `k`. This removes the need to loop through all values of `x` an allows for a solution in `O(n)` time.

Pseudocode:

```
Keep an integer "sl" to store the index of l that gives the current LIS
Keep an integer "sr" to store the length of the current LIS, initialized to 0
Keep an integer "tl" to store the current index of l
Keep an integer "tr" to store the current length if l were to be at tl, initialized to 0
Keep a boolean "used" to remember whether we've used the a[i]+x rule yet
For each value of i from 0 to n-2:
    If (not used) and (a[i+1] <= a[i]) and (a[i+1]+x > a[i]):
        tl = i+1
        tr++
        used = true
    Else if (used) and (a[i+1] > a[i]):
        tr++
    Else:
        If (tr > sr):
            sr = tr
            sl = tl
        used = false
        tr = 1
If (tr > sr):
    sl = tl

Keep an array "b" of size n, initialized to be the same as the given array a
For each value of i from sl to n-1:
    b[i] += k
return b
```

This algorithm is `O(n)` because it runs one loop through all the items `a`, which is `n` items.

Cheers.

Comment: But the $b$ sequence is not given. You want to create the b sequence with longest increasing subsequence and calculate the longest increasing subsequence as well.

Comment: ...then what's the point of x? you need to be much clearer with your question if you want a clear answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Our inputs are the two natural numbers n, k and the sequence a. Our output should be the longest increasing subsequence that can be created through a sequence b. The variable x (probably because I obviously don't know the answer to the question) is used to describe the sequences b and their relation to the sequence a.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I'll edit my solution to work for your problem.

Comment: Should answer the question now. Tell me if this helps.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In this way don't you just compare elements that are next to each other? For example $a_1$ with $a_2$. But the longest increasing subsequence doesn't have to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

All indices below are understood to take valid values.

As expected, we will use dynamic programming.

Consider an increasing subsequence of
$$a_1,\cdots a_{l-1}, a_l+x, a_{l+1}+x, \cdots, a_r+x, a_{r+1}, \cdots, a_n$$
that ends at element $a_e$ or $a_e+x$.

Classify that subsequence

- by $(e, 0,``\text{before"})$ if $e<l$
- by $(e, x,``\text{added"})$ if $l\le e\le r$
- by $(e, x,``\text{after"})$ if $e>r$ and that sequence contains at least one element of the form $a_i+x$.

Let $dp[e][x][stage]$ be the length of the longest sequence that is classified by $(e, x, stage)$, where $1\le e\le n$, $-k\le x\le k$, $stage$ is one of $``\text{before"}$, $``\text{added"}$ and $``\text{after"}$.

What we are asked to compute is the maximum of all $dp[e][x][stage]$.

We have the following recurrence relations: (function $\max$ takes value $0$ if its arguments turn out to be empty)

$$dp[e][0][``\text{before"}]=1 + \max_{d<e\text{ and }a_d<a_e}dp[d][0][``\text{before"}]$$

$$dp[e][x][``\text{added"}]=1 + \max(\max_{d<e\text{ and }a_d<a_e+x}dp[d][0][``\text{before"}],\ \max_{d<e\text{ and }a_d<a_e}dp[d][x][``\text{added"}])$$

$$dp[e][x][``\text{after"}]=1 + \max(\max_{d<e\text{ and }a_d+x<a_e}dp[d][x][``\text{added"}],\ \max_{d<e\text{ and }a_d<a_e}dp[d][x][``\text{after"}])$$

The first recurrence relation is, in fact, (one of) the usual recurrence relation that is used to compute the longest increasing subsequence of a sequence.

The base cases are $dp[1][0][``\text{before"}]=dp[1][x][``\text{added"}]=dp[1][x][``\text{after"}]=1$ for all $x$.

(By the way, $dp[e][0][``\text{before"}]=dp[e][0][``\text{added"}]$ for all $e$. So we can remove stage $``\text{before"}$.)

The time-complexity is $O(kn^2)$ since, basically, there are $O(nk)$ entries to compute and it takes $O(n)$ to compute each entry.

---

If we adapt the $O(n\log n)$-time algorithm for the usual longest subsequence problem, we will have a $O(kn\log n)$ algorithm.

Comment: Can we do any changes so the complexity doesn't include k?

Comment: @Hjm Yes. Are you interested in $O(n^3\log n)$ time?

Comment: Yes, if you can tell me how to achieve it